# Can I omit 'where' from the sentence

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, reduced-relative-clauses

> This is the house which we live in.
> =This is the house that we live in.

Then the relative pronoun 'that' is omitted. So the sentence becomes:
*This is the house we live in.*

Am I correct?

Now what if there's 'where' in the place of 'which'? Can I omit it?

> This is the house where we live.

Can I reduce the sentence to:*This is the house we live*.

Comment: No, you can't. _Where_ means the same as _in which_, so if you drop _where_ you lose the sense of _in_.

Comment: I agree with Kate.  You "live *in* a house", you don't "live a house", so you can't say "the house we live".

Comment: @KateBunting ok I got it. I think there's an exception. "This is the place where we met" can be reduced to "This is the place we met". So 'where' can be omitted when it's preceded by the word 'place'. Am I right?

Comment: No, you need "that" + "in" at the end, or "where", Note that if we replace "house" with the more general noun "place" it's then OK to say "This is the place we live" but not *"This is the house we live".

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say "This is the place we met", but no doubt people do say it...

Comment: "This is the place we met" is fine, but not, say, *"This is the hotel we first met". The reason is that in sentences with more general head nouns a bare relative is usually acceptable.